# Is there any way to add a new parameter to a function programmatically?

Tags: javascript

Since I can determine the number of arguments a function expects to have by calling its `Function.length` property, is there any way for me to programmatically create the right number of parameters to insert into that function at runtime? Example:

```
var xyz = function(a,b) {};
var bcd = function(a,b,c,d,e,f) { }; // vararg example
var doc = document, func_length = xyz.length;
doc.xyz = (function() {

   return function(a,b,c,d,e) { /* works for one but not the other */ } }).call(doc);

   /* would prefer to `return function(a,b)` with only 2 parameters, if it is
   used for function `xyz` (though returning 5 works fine in this case), and to
   `return function(a,b,c,d,e,f)` with 6 if used for function `bcd` (which does
   not work with only five params). */

   // thinking about xyz.apply(null,arguments)...but which arguments..? :(

   // Returning function(a,b,c,d,e) does not support functions with more than five 
   // parameters...which would mostly be varargs - hence my question

   // I am also well aware that I can use an object or an array instead of
   // using many params.

   /* This is for incorporating a user-defined function for use in my code, while 
    * allowing for my function to do 'other stuff' afterward. (And allowing for 
    * varargs, of course).
    * Because coding something like: doc.xyz = xyz is inflexible */
```

As you can see, I don't know how to do this, or if it is even possible. The search bar hasn't given me any other questions like this one, otherwise I would not have asked...

Comment: Just ignore that the fact that you have 5 parameters and pass two arguments. It should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
NOTE: This answer is a product of misunderstanding but
      may help the future visitors of this site.
```

## Another way:

Do you really need to add parameters? Writing the function this way would be enough:

```
function foo(){ //No arguments predefined
 a = arguments[0] || ""; //first argument or (if not defined) empty string
 b = arguments[1] || ""; //second argument etc.
 c = arguments[2] || ""; //third argument etc.
 alert(a+b+c);
}
foo("Hello ", "world!");
```

This alerts "Hello world".

## The solution you want:

#### The simplest way:

This is what you've asked for but it's not as simple as the previous solution.
You can define a ***meta* function** with all the parameters and a **handler function** that changes over the time.

```
(function(){ //Wrapper

  var foo_meta = function(a,b,c,d){ //Local meta of foo
   alert(a+b+c+d); //Do the code
  };

  window.foo = function(a,b){ //Global foo
   return foo_meta(a,b,"","");
  };

  window.redefine_foo = function(){ //Global foo-changer
   //Rewrites foo
   window.foo = function(a,b,c){
    return foo_meta(a,b,c,"");
   };
  };

})(); //Wrapper

//Do some code
foo("a","b");

redefine_foo(); //Rewrite foo

foo("a","b","c");

//Note that foo_meta is not defined here
foo_meta == undefined; //It's safe in the wrapper :)
```

This will alert "ab" and then "abc". For the meaning of wrapper function, see the references.

## Reference:

Arguments array: http://goo.gl/FaLM1H
Wrapping code: http://goo.gl/uQ5sd0

Comment: JavaScript does not throw if you input less or more than the required amount of arguments, unless you specifically make a function throw in that situation. Also, was it intended to create globals in your first example?

Comment: @OneKitten Sorry, my fault.

Answer (score 0):

If you send two parameters 6 and 7 to a `function doWork(a,b,c,d,e),a=7 and b=6` will be automatically set and rest of the parameters will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I've figured it out at last. I've realized that there may be no way to 'truly' add a parameter to a function the way that I was asking, but there is a way to emulate the same result:

```
var doc = document;
var xyz = function(a,b) {};
var bcd = function(a,b,c,d,e,f) {};
var obj = {};

// Now, here it is (mostly (sort of)):

obj.userFunc = function(args) { 

var args_Array = [];

for (var i=0;i < arguments.length; i++ ) { 
    args_Array.push(arguments[i]) 
}
xyz.apply(null,args_Array); // or 'this'. or 'undefined'. Whatever you want.

// do other stuff

return this; // we know what to do to make 'this' scope explicit

} // end

var thisFunc = 'xyz'
doc[thisFunc] = obj.userFunc;
doc.xyz('h','i');
doc.xyz('h','i','j');
doc.xyz('h','i','j','k'); 
doc.xyz('h','i').xyz('j','l').xyz('j','q'); // etc.
```

The trick was to use the `arguments` object, which conveniently assimilated all the parameters into a readily available object, push each value into an array then `apply` the function.

In case you're wondering what the fuss was all about, I wanted to completely incorporate a user-defined function into another function, while still being able to do 'other stuff' afterward. My previous example worked to an extent, but did not have support for varargs. This does.

This approach is greatly more flexible than: `doc[thisFunc] = userDefinedFunction`

:) 4/26/2014

Comment: So your goal is to have a function that _does something_ and then passes all the arguments to another function?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for joining the arguments, regardless of the number of arguments, to show how function arguments can be turned into an array and then processed like any other array.

```
function foo(){ //No arguments predefined
  // convert to real array
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  // or if Array generics are available
  var args = Array.slice(arguments);
  console.log(args.join(' '));
}

foo('Hello', 'world!');
foo('Hello', 'wonderful', 'world!');
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P7JPY/1/)

Ref: [arguments MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass one object into the function and use JQuery extend.

e.g.

```
var parm = 

{  x: 1, y : 2};

f(p) {
   p = $_.extend({...defaults here}, p);
...

}
```

Comment: Uhm...I currently know almost nothing about how `$.extend` really works - have to check up on it.